# Horizontal center vertically aligned equations

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, align, amsmath

I am using Doxygen to build some C source code documentation. I have the following:

```
@f{align*}
 R_n = R_{n - 1} \pm \left[(slope \times T) \times \frac{1}{ref}\right], \\
     \forall R \in [0,1)
@f}
```

Where `@f{align*}` is equivalent to selecting an environment in the manner of `\begin{align*}` (and `@f}` marks the end of the environment).

Or more technically, the Doxygen documentation says:

> **\f{environment}{**
>
> Marks the start of a formula that is in a specific environment.

This is used because I would like the "∀R ∈ [0, 1)" to be on a second line, instead of being on the same line as, and immediately after, the formula itself.

The above LaTeX achieves this but how can I maintain centre alignment in the horizontal instead of aligning to some fixed point with `&`? Without the `&` it defaults to: first line align left, last line align right.

Or should I use a different method of vertical alignment to achieve this?

Comment: `multline` would give different alignments for different rows but `align*` would align all rows the same way. But it is the wrong environment if there is no alignment use `gather*` for  multiple equations or `multline` for one multiple lien ewuation.

Comment: `slope` and `ref` should not be set in math italic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

I suspect you want `gather`

```
\documentclass{article}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}


align*\dotfill X
\begin{align*}
 R_n = R_{n - 1} \pm \left[(\mathrm{slope} \times T) \times \frac{1}{\mathrm{ref}}\right], \\
     \forall R \in [0,1)
\end{align*}

align* with \&\dotfill X
\begin{align*}
 R_n &= R_{n - 1} \pm \left[(\mathrm{slope} \times T) \times \frac{1}{\mathrm{ref}}\right], \\
     &\forall R \in [0,1)
\end{align*}

gather*\dotfill X
\begin{gather*}
 R_n = R_{n - 1} \pm \left[(\mathrm{slope} \times T) \times \frac{1}{\mathrm{ref}}\right], \\
     \forall R \in [0,1)
\end{gather*}

multline*\dotfill X
\begin{multline*}
 R_n = R_{n - 1} \pm \left[(\mathrm{slope} \times T) \times \frac{1}{\mathrm{ref}}\right], \\
     \forall R \in [0,1)
\end{multline*}

[ and split\dotfill X
\[\begin{split}
 R_n = R_{n - 1} \pm \left[(\mathrm{slope} \times T) \times \frac{1}{\mathrm{ref}}\right], \\
     \forall R \in [0,1)
\end{split}\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the `\mathrm` suggestion too!